# Add footer view UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this code to add a footer view to my table view

```
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,320.0f,80.0f)];

    UILabel *tableFooter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
tableFooter.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
tableFooter.backgroundColor = [self.tableView backgroundColor];
tableFooter.opaque = YES;
tableFooter.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
tableFooter.text = @"test";

[footerView addSubview:tableFooter];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

but then I when I run this I do not see the label at the bottom of my code, I am it to my view, and then set my view as to footer, I see the extra space but not the label?

Not sure why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Try changing the width of `footerView` to something greater than 0, maybe 320, and see if that works.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam still nothing there

Comment: Try `footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]` to see if your footer is appearing at all.

Comment: In which function are you adding the footer view?

Comment: @ChrisLoonam cellForRowAtIndexPath, and I see the extra space added

Comment: @NealEhardt did that and I see the red

Comment: Did you also set the height of footerView greater than or equal to the height of label?

Comment: Try moving it to a different function like `viewDidLoad:`, and are you implementing the delegate methods related to footer views (`tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`, etc.)?

Comment: @mithleshjha yes, look at code label is 20 wide and tall, view is 320x80

Comment: @ChrisLoonam But in viewDidLoad shouldn't matter because I see the view being added, I just don't see the label being added to to view?

Comment: Yes, but the issue may lie in the fact that `cellForRow:` is called multiple times, depending on how many cells you have. I'd personally move any code related to creating the view to `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` and return the view in that function.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam okay but I don't want a footer at each section I want just one at the end of the table view

Comment: @iqueqiorio If you only want a footer for the whole table, do it in `viewDidLoad`.  Your code looks fine.  There's no need for `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`.

Comment: Try to get the dimensions of your UILabel after the layout has settled.  My guess is that this is a layout issue.  Maybe save the label as an ivar and log its frame from an event `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(myLabel.frame));`

Comment: @ChrisLoonam Those are bad options. The table view footer (or header) should be created and added in `viewDidLoad`, not any of the table view delegate or data source methods.